# How to pass --properties-file to spark-submit in Qubole?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-submit, qubole

I am using Spark in Qubole by having the clusters created in AWS.  In ***Qubole Workbench***, when I execute the below Command Line, it works fine and the command is successful

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit s3://bucket-name/SparkScripts/test.py`

But, when I execute the same command along with --properties-file option

`/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --properties-file s3://bucket-name/SparkScripts/properties.file s3://bucket-name/SparkScripts/test.py`

it gives below error message

> Qubole > Shell Command failed with exit code: 1
>
> App > Error occurred when getting effective config required to initialize Qubole security provider
>
> App > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Properties file s3:/bucket-name/SparkScripts/properties.file does not exist

Can someone help me fix this?  I need some application properties to be stored on a separate file on Amazon S3 and passed on to --properties-file to my spark program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@saravanan - Qubole does not have the ability to specify --properties file from S3 path currently. It will be available in release 59.